# Opening new tab in Ionic2 app

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to add a new tab to the app, just as info page. The extra page is added and I created a new tab but it is not working at all. Not even displaying a basic ionic details. I have added the new page in app.module.ts and also in tabs folder.

tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { InfoPage } from '../info/info';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
tab1Root: any = HomePage;
tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
tab3Root: any = ContactPage;
tab4root: any = InfoPage;
constructor() {
}
}

tabs.html

<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Geo" tabIcon="md-globe"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="info" tabIcon="football"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
 MyApp,
 AboutPage,
 ContactPage,
 HomePage,
 ScanPage,
 TabsPage,
 InfoPage
 ],
 imports: [
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
 ],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
 entryComponents: [
 MyApp,
 AboutPage,
 ContactPage,
 HomePage,
 ScanPage,
 TabsPage,
 InfoPage
 ],
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your `tabs.html` ? Maybe you missed to add `[root]="tab4Root"`

Comment: @AndreaRega   nope., I have added that as well..